# Magento: Can't make the search bar appear

Tags: magento, search, content-management-system, searchbar

I'm trying to make a search bar appear and I can't.
Not only in the header but also in any page if I try to paste the basic search bar code, nothing will appear, can someone tell me where should I check to see if I'm missing any code?
in that case, what code and where should I add to finally be able to integrate a search bar in my header / home page or wherever?

{{block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"}}
Note: this code didn't work in any page whatsoever

Also, for some reason I seem to be missing a lot of options from plugins and magento itself (Look at hot the banner slider only has one option and when I try to edit a Slider I also get alot less options than what the plugin has to offer)
http://screencast.com/t/hsH9scDo4

Answer (score 0):

Check your store view in System>Configuration>Design>Themes and see what it says there as the templates and layout name. (not to be confused with system>design). Make sure it says default/modern or just modern.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the search element via xml in a custom layout file. For that create a local.xml file in your theme layout folder and paste following code for adding the search bar to the header:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Put that code under the layout/default xml tags, and don't forget to add addChildHtml('topSearch') to your .phtml head file.